# is there a way to get the Y-values to appear on the right for a ASP.NET chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts

I am trying to get the Y values for my chart to appear on the right rather than the left. After digging around in the MSDN documentation and searching on the net I have not found a way to do this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. System.Web.Helpers is a wrapper around System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting. You have to use the latter if you want the full functionality. The property I wanted is called XAxisType and is a member of the Series class.

So the code to enable the X axis to appear on the right is something like:

```
seriesDetail.XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
```